# Reducing number of decimal places after X/Y coordinates in a FC

Tags: python, arcpy

I'm using arcpy.AddXY_management to add coordinates, and I want to reduce each X/Y field by x number. I've tried to reduce it by string slicing and that obviously didn't work. I also tried setting the precision but that doesn't work on FC's. Anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 4):

After you run ADD XY, run Calculate Field on each X/Y field.
You just need the following in the expression (set the the expression type to PYTHON)

```
round(!POINT_Y!, 2)
```

and

```
round(!POINT_X!, 2)
```

Where 2 = the number of decimal places.

Comment: I got an error when I tried this. Does it matter which field type point_x and point_y are defined as? I tried the round function on another field, so its not my syntax.

Comment: I changed the field type to "float" and it now works fine. I had it set to "double" and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why string slicing wouldn't work, so long as your fields are strings. Try this with table tableName that has two fields, POINT_X and POINT_Y that you want to reduce to int x numbers:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "yourFCPath"
arcpy.AddField_management("tableName", "newX", "TEXT", "", "", "20")
arcpy.AddField_management("tableName", "newY", "TEXT", "", "", "20")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("tableName", "newX", 
                                '!POINT_X![:x]', "PYTHON")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("tableName", "newY", 
                                '!POINT_Y![:x]', "PYTHON")
```

I don't see anywhere in documentation the output data type of arcpy.AddXY_management but if your fields are float/double instead of strings simply replace the last two lines with:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management("tableName", "newX", 
                                'str(!POINT_X!)[:x]', "PYTHON")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("tableName", "newY", 
                                'str(!POINT_Y!)[:x]', "PYTHON")
```